# Assistance with Forms Authentication and Custom Roles

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, formsauthentication

I am working on a asp.net website and I am having trouble implementing a custom role provider using forms authentication.

I have a SQL Server database "MyBase" with a "UserRoles" table which contains UserRoleID, EmployeeID, RoleID, and UserName fields.  I want to retrieve the roles for a user from this table when users log in using a custom login page (just a couple textboxes, labels, and a button).

I have searched/read several questions, scenarios, and examples but I'm still missing something somewhere so I'm reaching out for some assistance.

What I have done so far:

In web.config:

- Set authentication mode to forms
- Set membership provider settings
- Set role provider settings

I have created the follow custom classes and listed sub/function/properties:

- RoleProvider 
  --GetRolesForUser
  --IsUserInRole
  --ApplicationName
- MembershipProvider
  --GetUser
  --UpdateUser
  --ValidateUser
- MembershipUser

In my login button:

1. I encrypt the user's password.
2. Call my custom MembershipProviders' ValidateUser `MemProv.ValidateUser(txt_username.Text, encrypedPW)`which returns true or false correctly.
3. Call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txt_username.Text, False)`
4. Call my custom RoleProvider's GetRolesForUser function: `RoleProv.GetRolesForUser(txt_Username.Text)` which returns a String() or roles correctly.

When I check my User.Identity, isAuthenticated = false and Name = "".

I'm pretty sure I am missing an implementation of IIdentity and/or IPrincipal, but I don't know where/how to implement them.

So my questions are:

1. Do I need to go through all of this just to keep my roles in a SQL Server table I created?
2. Do I need to incorporate IIDentity and IPrincipal? If so, how do I or where do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two classes that implement IPrincipal and IIdentity.

In the Principal's IsInRole function I make a call to my custom RoleProvider's IsUserInRole function.

I logged using my custom login page and was redirected to the correct form.  The Identity and RolePrincipal both contain the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

Re-create the MyBase database using the ASP.Net IIS Registration tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe). This will create the database necessary to store your membership information - properly.

Here's a link that gives more information:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).ASPX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

Comment: If my MembershipProvider and RoleProvider are accessing the current tables and returning the correct information how will re-creating the database help with the Identity and Principal issues?

Comment: I was under the impression that you created that table from scratch, sorry, you do say however that "When I check my User.Identity, isAuthenticated = false and Name = ""." so I'm wondering if it's possible that there's a problem with your database.

Comment: I've implemented Membership many times and never had to deal with implementing IPrincipal or IIdentity.

Comment: If you need a good tutorial on implementing IPrincipal there are many, here is one: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574576/How-to-implement-a-custom-IPrincipal-in-ASP-NET-MV

Comment: The "ball" seems to be being dropped where Identity properties are set. "MyRoleProvider" and "MyMembershipProvider" and doing part of their job with data retrieval, but somewhere I am missing where the User information is set.  Thanks for the link.  I've been looking into some tutorials on how do implement those interfaces.  I'm hoping I'm heading in the right direction.  Thanks again

Comment: Are you referring to Profile information for example things like Age, Favorite Color etc?

Comment: There will be additional user specific information used once the basic functionality is there such as accessing IsAuthenticated, Name, etc.